# Different atmospheres

Tags: science-based, climate, atmosphere

So in my world, I will have different atmospheres I won't go into much details on how they work but I wanted to ask what would be some interesting compositions you might think of to make them unique, for example one of them would have a lot of oxygen (like Earth millions of years ago) making life huge (dinosaurs and giant insects) and also making fire burn super hot.

If you could give me an example and how it would affect the world. 2 things all atmosphere will require some oxygen, toxic gases don't matter because I have other ways of dealing with those so feel free to include them. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please define what makes something interesting, else it is a whole matter of opinion: as an example some people find interesting stamps while some other are interested in motorbikes. Moreover we prefer to deal with well defined problems which can be answered in a measurable way. You can find more info on what makes a good question in our [help]

Comment: I think it would be interesting to have one atmosphere where everyone had a squeaky voice and you were not allowed to smoke because of all the hydrogen.  But really Dutch is right.  You need to define interesting as regards the story you are telling using your fictional world.

Comment: Nice scenario to think about, Miguel ! The answer was edited by me, I corrected a few spelling errors.

Comment: I agree with all the above; "Interesting" depends on what you wish, inside your world as a character living in it or outside as the designer. Even a "boring" Earth-atmosphere can be interesting if air is not the focus of your world :).

Answer (score 2):

**Flammable VOC**
Worlds like Titan have mostly methane-based atmospheres which are volatile organic hydrocarbons (VOC), but there’s nothing to say oxygen couldn’t co-exist with these flammable gases.

However, on a world with a large amount of VOCs you get interesting scenarios such as “forest fires” that actually burn the atmosphere instead of trees. The rain and water in such worlds could also be flammable. Maybe even the organisms living there, if mostly liquid, would be extremely flammable or even explosive.

**Plasma**
Strong electromagnetic fields from a nearby pulsar or neutron star could cause the atmosphere to become an ionized plasma. Your life forms would be living inside a neon light, so to speak. Communication would be different as ‘sound’ would be much closer to electricity than air pressure waves. Sight might even be more useful as an electromagnetic sensory mechanism, like what hammerhead sharks do.

**Oil water scenario**
Oil floats on water, but several gases could float on top of each other within an atmosphere. Layers and stratification might be possible in such a scenario; where you could effectively swim in a highly dense layer, but fly in a less dense layer.

**All atmosphere**
There are many gas giants that are basically all atmosphere. The core is likely some kind of molten metal. In an all gas planet maybe every life form has to fly to survive, and can never land.

**All fire**
If there is too much oxygen, things would constantly spontaneously combust and oxidize. It’s feasible that everything is on fire all the time, and perhaps Calcifer from the *Howl’s Moving Castle* novels is from that planet.

**Gaseous metal (yes)**
Metals are elements like oxygen. Technically you could have gaseous metal atmospheres. Seems like a few exoplanets we’ve discovered are so close to their orbiting star that their atmosphere may have liquid and gaseous metals. Perhaps the chemistry changes in that scenario and then you can start having fluid, DNA-looking silicon based life forms. Silicon is maybe molten and gaseous in that world and is like oxygen on ours. You mention you need oxygen, so I’m assuming human-type life exists there too. So maybe this is a stretch.

**Incredible buoyancy**
Like in gas giants, you could have a planet with tonnes of helium or hydrogen, (inert or explosive, respectively). In this case it might be really easy for huge whale-like animals to float off and fly.

**Ravaging, eternal storms**
Jupiter’s red spot and Saturn’s hexagon storm are good examples of the eternal storms on some worlds. We’re lucky our storms are temporary but it seems quite common to have a planet with giant storms that are fixed in place with winds stronger than any hurricane on earth. If I had to venture a guess I would say most life forms on such a planet would live underground or underwater. That or they would be so materially dense/aerodynamic that strong winds are not a problem.

Your question reminds me of working in low-oxygen environments several years ago. I often wondered, for my own survival, how the atmosphere would affect me if my oxygen mask were to fail and how much time I would have to run out of the tunnels. Plot spoiler: about 3 minutes.